# Probability of a point in the unit square being in the interval (a,b)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X, Y)$ denote a uniformly chosen random point inside the unit square, $$[0,1]^2=[0,1]\times[0,1]=\{(x,y):0\le x\le1,\ 0\le y \le1\}$$

(a). Let $ 0\le a\lt b\le1$ find the probability $P(a\lt X\lt b)$, that is the probability that the $x$-coordinate $X$ of the chosen point lies in the interaval $(a,b)$.

(b). What is the probability $P(|X-Y|\le 1/4)$ ?

For (a), I know that the probability of finding a point on the interval $(a,b)$ is simply $b-a$, but for this point $X$ wouldn't the answer still just be $b-a$ since only the $y$-coordinate is changing. What am I missing here?

Comment: When you have two variables, area represents probability. Since the area of the unit square is 1, the probability that a point is inside a set $S$ will just be the area of $S$. Hence, the probability that $x$ is between $a$ and $b$ is the area of the rectangle $(a,b)\times [0,1]$, which is just $(b-a)(1-0)=b-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vX}{\textbf{X}} \vX:=(X,Y)$ is a Uniform random variable on $[0,1]^2$, i.e. its probability density function, $f_\vX$ is constant. Since $|[0,1]^2| = 1$, the pdf is 1. Then

$$P((X,Y) ∈ A) = \iint_A f_\vX(x,y) \ dx \ dy = \iint_A dx \ dy = |A| $$

Also note that $X$ and $Y$ are independent because $f_\vX(x,y)$ trivially splits into the form $f(x)g(y)$. Hence we know that the marginal distribution of $X$ is $f_X(x) = 1$.

- (a): your intuition is correct. If you don't want to use the above argument, you can also compute $P(X∈ I) = ∬_{I\times[0,1]} dx \ dy = ∫_I dx = |I|$.
- (b): **hint.** We can write $\{ |X-Y| \le 1/4\}$ as
  \begin{align} \left\{ |X-Y| \le \frac{1}{4}\right\} &= \left\{X > Y,\ X\le Y+\frac{1}{4} \right\}∪\left\{X \le Y,\ X\ge Y-\frac{1}{4} \right\}\\ &= \left\{ Y< X\le Y+\frac{1}{4} \right\}∪\left\{Y-\frac{1}{4}\le X\le Y \right\}  \end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the response. For part (b) I used the equation given and just plotted out the possible area, but your solution is much more elegant, thank you!

Comment: @JimGross You're welcome :) I prefer the plot, honestly. 

If your questions are answered please accept the answer :D